# MediaRouter BT active audio source id or MAC address

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, mediarouter

I need the `active audio source id` or `MAC address` to compare it with my own list of `Bluetooth devices`. `MediaRouter.getSelectedRoute` gives very basic information like the `name`, `type of the device`. I see there is a `getAddress()` API which is hidden in `MediaRouter` class. Is there any other unique id to identify and compare the `BT` devices with my own list. `Name` field is not reliable as there can be multiple devices with same name. 
Also, `Samsung` devices can have multiple `Bluetooth` devices active at the same time. Didn't find any API which can give the correct information.

```
        val mediaRouter = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE) as MediaRouter
        val selectedRoute = mediaRouter.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO)
        Log.e("MainActivity", "route:" + selectedRoute)
```

Also, tried the below for `Samsung` devices. This gives the connected device list but not the active device.

```
 List<BluetoothDevice> a2dpList = bluetoothProfileProxy.getConnectedDevices();
```

Comment: Since `MediaRouter` is not limited to Bluetooth devices, I am skeptical that there is any reliable way to map from `MediaRouter` to a Bluetooth MAC address.